# multiple refresh on browser with laravel 5.4 project get error "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

When i actually refresh my `blade` `view` for multiple times i will get error message `"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."` in `laravel 5.4` but there are no error in my code and no error message display only a header `"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."` but when i am try to refresh one more it will show my view as normal.

i try to copy `.env.example` to `.env` but i got error message

```
RuntimeException in Encrypter.php line 43:
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

why only refresh `blade view` on browser get error is anyone can tell me what is this error message?? and how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

Please check you have added `config/app.php`

```
'cipher' => 'AES-128-CBC',
```

Hope this work for you !

Answer (score -1):

Have you generated an application key? If not try: `php artisan key:generate`

Otherwise try cleaning up your config cache: `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: application key is auto generate when my project create

Comment: I had this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080) a bunch of times where I had to regenerate it or clear the config cache.

Comment: yes it's rarely happen but if i try to refresh my page many and many time it will show this error but no content about error message like other error message i am wonder what is this error and how to fix it

Comment: Have you checked in the logs? Ensure that `APP_DEBUG=true` in .env file and try looking at `/storage/laravel.log` file for any additional information.

Comment: yes APP_DEBUG= true in my .env file. if i use php artisan key:generate it will generate new application key??

Comment: Yes that should do it!

Comment: I'm happy to help! Good luck!

Comment: i try your answer already but when i try to refresh page it still got this error

Comment: when i see this error and then i refresh my page one more it will show my blade view as simple